# Cat sorted files

Tags: linux, find, sort, cat

I would like to sort files after finding them and then *cat* them into another text file.

I tried:

`find filename -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} \; | sort > result.txt`

but it is not working. I think it first *cat* into file and afther that sort. But i wanted *cat* already sorted files .

Comment: Order of operations.  `find` → `sort` → `cat`; not `find` → `cat` → `sort`.

Comment: How is it "not working"? I mean, what is happening? Assuming that `filename` is actually a directory, that should work as expected: this will find all `.txt` files, cat all of them, pass that to `sort` and save the sorted output into a new file. Is that not what you are seeing? What are you seeing instead?

Comment: Wait, do you mean you want to sort the file _names_ and not their contents?

Comment: It's unclear what the outcome should be. Should it be 1) the sorting of all files concatenated (no, that's what you're doing already), or 2) the concatenation of each file sorted, or 3) concatenation of the files after their _names_ have been sorted, or, 4) the sorting of the list of names and nothing else?  Please clarify your question. Consider using words like "filenames" or "file's content" to make it explicit what you're working with.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `xargs` for `cat` in that case, for safety reasons I suggest using zero-delimited outputs for `find`

```
 find filename -name '*.txt' -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 cat  > combined.txt
```

**What it does:**

- find the files => `C.txt A.txt B.txt`
- sort by file**names** => `A.txt B.txt C.txt`
- concatenate the files **in this order** => `cat A.txt B.txt C.txt`
- **no** sorting of the individual file contents nor the cumulated content

Comment: Thank you very much !!

Comment: This sorts filenames, then concatenates them. It's not clear from the question that this is what's wanted.  In fact, the question says "I want to _sort files_".

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, added clarity in my answer. The question allows for multiple interpretations, I agree.